# When will Nexus 6 get Android security updates?

Tags: ota-update, nexus-6

I am using a Nexus 6 with H2O wireless network. The July 1st 2016 security patch has been out for several days (since July 5) but my phone still doesn't get it. Do Nexus phones get updates directly from Google or through carriers? When can I get that update?

Comment: One option to get the latest security updates as soon as they are out, is use a custom ROM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can take up to two weeks or so for the full rollout. I just received the July update this afternoon on my Nexus 5X.

Comment: My wife's Nexus 5X did get the update yesterday. I guess I just need to be a little more patient. Thanks.